# Using 2 css framework in one Ember project?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I made an ember bootstrap site but I don't like the responsive look on mobile so I want to make a mobile version using a mobile UI framework .

It seems that if I can reuse the routes and models already defined instead of creating a new project , that would be great.

so can Ember allow me to do something like this?

- check UA to load a difference configuration
- load different templates but same model, route, component
- same url but different site(mobile version)

-Hao

Answer (score 0):

I think [ember-responsive](https://github.com/freshbooks/ember-responsive) is the solution to your problem.
You can define breakpoints for various versions and then you can check in your controllers, components, views, templates and routes in which version you are currently in. Based on that you can change your templates and adjust them for your mobile version for example.